# В pycharm print не выводит результат в консоль

Tags: python, pycharm, print

[image: Версии питона и pycharm последние, результата выполнения принт нет, но если пробовать через отладчик, то все нормально. В чем может быть ошибка?]

Версии питона и pycharm последние, результата выполнения принт нет, но если пробовать через отладчик, то все нормально, вывод есть. В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена - антивирус Comodo блокировал консоль. После настройки антивируса, проблема исчезла.